# Retrieve the value from a JSONP formatted data object

Tags: javascript, json, esri, arcmap

Just when I think I've got he hang of identifying an element in an object, I run into a scenario that I cannot seem to get the value I want.

**This part works and the data returned is correct:**  I have a map and when I attempt to identify a building on the map, I receive the following json object *(this has been shortened for readability but in real life, its properly formatted)*: The function MapClick(queryResults) is called when the map is clicked.

```
dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript19._jsonpCallback({
"results": [
    {
        "layerId": 5,
        "layerName": "Building",
        "value": "Name of item clicked",
        "displayFieldName": "name",
        "attributes": {
            "ID": "123",
            "name": "Name of item clicked",
            "Variable1": "Some bit of information",
            "Variable2": "Some other bit of information",
            ...
            ...
```

All I'm trying to do is return either the `results[0].value` OR `results[0].attributes.name` which in this example should bring back "Name of item clicked". *The layerId, layerName, value, and displayFieldName are the "common most accessed data" so they are returned but the same information is also found within the attributes.*

I've tried `console.log(results[1].attributes.name);` and `console.log(results)` with no success.

Comment: You probably need `results.results[0].value`. The top level object has the property `results`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Are you saying the top level will always be `results` and just so happens in this json object being returned, `results` is also used and that's what you are suggesting the `results.results[0].value` might work?  In other words if the example provide above had been response, the answer might be `results.response[0].value`?

Comment: The first `result` is the name of the variable you are using, which you can change however you want to. The second `result` is the name of the property in the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the name of the function handling the MapClicked is queryResults was needed so the correct answer is:  `queryResults[0].value` and when you see open brackets `[`, you can be sure you will need `[` some number `]` (e.g. `queryResults[0].value` or `queryResults[99].someothervariable`.  Or at least I think this is a correct statement.